# Word for the inability to do simple things when you don't look at it

Tags: terminology, science

Well, the title says it all. I'll add an example:

You try to put a plug into a socket which is under the table and you're too lazy to stoop down.
To my mind this sounds like a very simple task and still I sometimes fail to get it in and I eventually bend my head down and once I look at it, I can immediately plug it in.

Comment: **"Normal"**.................

Comment: There are a few ways to describe this common phenomena, can you provide a sentence with a (blank) where you want the word/sentence to go?

Comment: Poor kinesthetic sense, perhaps?

Comment: Isn't that just being lazy?

Comment: @Minnow - which is also fairly normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Aproprioceptive**.

[Proprioception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprioception) is the sense of knowing where your hands (or other parts) are.

[Aproprioception](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/259576371_Aproprioception_gesture_and_cognitive_being) is the loss of proprioception:

> Aproprioception renders practical action nearly impossible, without mental concentration and visual supervision...

Comment: Probably not a correct answer. Proprioception is the sense of where our body is in space _provided only by internal sources_ such as muscle spindles and Golgi tendons. It is usually sub-conscious and doesn't change significantly. It is indeed involved in non-visual motor tasks. Aproprioception is a term coined by the paper to describe a loss of internal coordination experienced by a single subject, to date. It has no bearing on the decrease in motor accuracy when no visual feedback is available.

Answer (score 1):

"word for the inability..." suggests you are looking for a noun, not an adjective. I'd go for"**clumsiness**", or "**awkwardness**"

> clumsy - adj. "awkward in handling things" [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clumsy), "lacking dexterity" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clumsy)

or, as has been suggested in a comment by @Oldcat, "**normal**" (adj), if you consider that there are a lot of people who find it difficult to perform tasks with their hands without looking at what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The verb that comes to mind in decribing the action you are referring to is:

To [grope](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grope):

> - to search for something by reaching or touching usually with your fingers in an awkward way.
>
>   - I groped for the light switch.
>   - She groped around in her purse, looking for her comb.

also to [struggle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/struggle) may be useful to describe the action:

> - to try to move yourself, an object, etc., by making a lot of effort
>     in the end

I struggled to reach the plug under the table without bendind, but in the end  I had to stoop down to put the plug in.